# Syncing Outlook, gmail, calendar and contacts

Tags: sync, android, microsoft-outlook-2010, google-calendar

My previous phone was a Windows Mobile 6.5 HTC. I had it linked to my computer (Windows 7 Professional 64-bit) and it used Windows Mobility Center to sync with Outlook 2010.
Everything was fine. I also added GMail by IMAP in Outlook.

But now I have this awesome brand new HTC Desire with Android 2.1. It asked for my Google account. Now I ended up with contacts in Outlook, the phone and GMail. The calendar in Outlook and Google Calendar and I have HTC Sync and Google Sync and I don't know what the best setup is. Does anyone have an idea?

I'd like to have the same in my Outlook contacts as in my GMail, Google cal, phone etc. So I'd like to sync everything with everything and could use some help. Because I have contacts in Outlook that are not in GMail and people on my phone which are not in GMail etc. Since I am on Android it's kind of hard.

**EDIT:**
Update from the Android forum:
As pointed out in the [answers](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1673/sync-setup-question-android-outlook-2010-gmail-calendar-and-contacts), I should *NOT* sync my phone with Outlook, but should sync Outlook to GMail. Google has a calendar sync tool, which is great, but does not sync the contacts. Now I've found KiGoo but I don't trust them yet. Can anyone recommend a good (preferably free and/or open source) app for syncing Outlook 2010 with GMail?

Comment: @BloodPhilia - except that Gadgets is [being shutdown](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/pruning-season/)...

Comment: @DMA57361 In that case, let me recomment and thanks for the notice! - It's not REALLY off topic since it involves syncing with PC software, however I feel that you might get more and better answers at http://android.stackoverflow.com which will be out of private beta in 4 days.

Comment: So i have to wait for 4 days to ask it there. or does someone know a way to set it up to sync three ways

Comment: Someone might have an answer for you here, and I don't see it being a problem if they do - as BloodPhilia has said you question isn't off-topic, it's just approaching the border between this an another (soon to exist) SE site. Unfortunatly, I can't help myself - but hopefully someone else can, and if you don't get a response in a reasonable time try editing your question with more details to see if that helps nudge people in to answering.

Comment: k, posted this question on http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1673/sync-setup-question-android-outlook-2010-gmail-calendar-and-contacts